# React onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I want to make a drop-down menu with a delay so that the user has the opportunity to hover over the drop-down items of the child list, but there is some kind of error here, I can't find it. Most likely this is a very easy mistake, it's just that my eye has blurred and I can't see it anymore
The idea is to hang the class on hover.show to class .bottom and get .

```
bottomUl.show {
        display: flex;
    }
```

instead of `display:none .`

**Array with nav meu bar:**

```
const navItems = [
    {
      label: 'Catalog',
      subItems: [
        { label: 'Cars new', link: '/catalog/new-car' },
        { label: 'Used Car', link: '/catalog/used-car' },
        { label: 'Offers', link: '/catalog/special-offers' },
      ],
    },
    {
      label: 'Services',
      subItems: [
        { label: 'Insurance', link: '/services/insurance' },
        { label: 'Accident assistant', link: '/services/accident-assistant' },
        { label: 'Number forcars', link: '/services/number-for-cars' },
      ],
    }
 ];
```

**React hook:**

```
const [hoveredItem, setHoveredItem] = useState(null);
  let timeoutId;

  const handleMouseEnter = (item) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setHoveredItem(item);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setHoveredItem(null);
    }, 400);
  };
```

**HTML:**

```
{navItems.map((item, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              className="menuEL"
              onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(item)}
              onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
            >
              {item.link ? (
                <Link href={item.link}>
                  <a rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <span>{item.label}</span>
                  </a>
                </Link>
              ) : (
                <span>{item.label}</span>
              )}
              {item.subItems && (
                <ul className={`bottomUl ${hoveredItem === item ? 'show' : ''}`}>
                  {item.subItems.map((subItem, subIndex) => (
                    <li
                      key={subIndex}
                      className={`f ${hoveredItem === item ? 'show' : ''}`}
                      onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(subItem)}
                      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
                    >
                      <Link href={subItem.link}>
                        <a rel="noopener noreferrer">{subItem.label}</a>
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              )}
            </li>
          ))}
```

**CSS:**

```
        ul {
            justify-content: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif'; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #0e0d0d;   
            font-size:18px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #0c54a0;
            border:none;
            z-index:9999;
            margin-top:0;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
            height: 92px;
            color:black;
            top:0;
        }
    
    .menuEL {
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            list-style: none;
            transition: 0.4s linear;
            position:relative;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            color:white;
        }
    
    
    bottomUl {
            display: none;
            flex-direction: column;        
            align-items: start;
            justify-content: start;
            margin-top:35px;
            width: 220px;
            height: auto;
            list-style: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: absolute;
            transition: 0.2s;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
    
        .bottomUl.show {
            display: flex;
        }


    .f{
        margin-top:5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
      
    .f:hover {
        color:#fdb913;;
    }


span:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        transform:scale(1.04);
        transition:0.2s;
    }

    a:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        transform:scale(1.04);
        transition:0.2s;
    }

    span:hover:after {
        cursor:pointer;
        width:100%;
        left:0;
    }
```

Comment: In your css, `bottomUl` should be `.bottomUl`.  What is the problem, though? What should happen that is not happening?

Comment: I found an error

Comment: The way you did it seems to be flawed: when you mouseEnter a subitem the `${hoveredItem === item ? 'show' : ''}` will not attach `show` and your `<ul>` will be `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

I found an error, I compared two arrays, but I needed two strings.

```
 onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(item.label)}

                <ul className={`bottomUl ${hoveredItem === item.label ? 'show' : ''}`}>
```